# What is this room in the Star Trek Adventures TNG tileset?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I'm currently mapping a Starfleet ship on Roll20 using the official Modiphius TNG-era tileset. These tiles are, to my knowledge, not labelled in any meaningful way; the following image is listed as "5x10_ST-FED-HT_8".

[image]

This caught my eye; it looks familiar and I'd like to use it in my campaign, but I can't name it or its purpose.

**Was this room ever explained on TNG or in a related technical manual?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image][image]

Seems like that lab where Locutus was studied and Geordi had his interface suit.  (May not be same room - labs tend to look alike)  Not a perfect match but may be the intent.

EDIT: certainly reuses the cybernetic lab props as seen in Michael's earlier answer.  It's not clear to me these are all the same room on the Enterprise as the walls seem different.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer possible, some alternate/generic cybernetics lab. Going with this for my map!

Comment: I suspect the room on OP's card has never shown up on screen.  I found a card deck listing that calls that card a "medbay/sickbay",  but it's clearly not the Enterprise sickbay.  The two rooms in the screenshots above were also recycled in countless episodes for a number of distinct uses, each time with a different central prop in the room (and the prop itself showed up in a different room per the other answer).  The prop itself is the only thing that matches, but the rooms are otherwise quite different.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like the cybernetics lab, seen in 'The Offspring' and 'Best of Both Worlds part 2'.

[image: Lal with Data Picard, and Troi in cybernetics lab]

[image: Enterprise cybernetics lab]

Comment: So this appears to be the same *prop* used in lucasbachmann's answer, but it's a completely different room.  Guess they liked that prop enough to use it in several episodes, but the rest of the set is not at all the same.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Reusing props as if nobody will ever notice is a hallowed Star Trek tradition: https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/reused_props_misc.htm

Comment: @JohnSmith Neat, though this prop isn't on the list - wonder if we should suggest an addition?